# How to subtract elements of two arrays and store the result as positive array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Assume i have 2 arrays,

```
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
B=[9,8,7,5,8,3]
```

When I subtract the elements of the array,

```
C=[-8,-6,-4,-1,-3,3]
```

How can I get the result of the subtraction as

```
C=[8,6,4,1,3,3]
```

Comment: How do you subtract the arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Math.abs()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs) is returning the absolute value of a number.

You could do something like

```
var A=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
var B=[9,8,7,5,8,3]

var C = [];
for(let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
  C.push(Math.abs(A[i] - B[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can  use the javascript function `Math.abs()`

```
C.map(Math.abs);
```

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Math.abs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/abs)

```
function absSubtract(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.map(function (el, i) {
    return Math.abs(el - arr1[i]);
  });
}

absSubtract(A, B); // [ 8, 6, 4, 1, 3, 3 ]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bjh5qdch/)

Answer (score 1):

```
C = A.map( (x, i) => x - B[i] ).map( x => Math.abs(x) );
```

Assuming that `A` and `B` are the same length.

Comment: wouldn't you want to combine the map functions to avoid iterating twice?

Comment: @Chic as a performance optimisation, yes. Though, as a performance optimisation, I’d probably hand-unwind the loop and say `C[0] = Math.abs( A[0] - B[0] );  /* ... */ C[5] = Math.abs(A[5] - B[5]);`  From a standpoint of testability, I would keep each function as simple, pure, and testable as possible, and then compose my solution. That might be a little contrived here, but when it comes to, say, filtering 5000 travel itineraries in a list, based on 12 different filters (and their settings), with criteria that might be in `itinierary.legs[0].segments[0].departureTime` or whatever - Purity first

Comment: True, performance usually isn't top priority. Composing was the term I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
    C[i] = Math.abs(A[i] - B[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution for the absolute difference. c = |a - b|

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    b = [9, 8, 7, 5, 8, 3],
    c = a.map(function (v, i) { return Math.abs(v - b[i]); });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(c, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```